# Ruby date formatting with arithmetic operators

Tags: ruby

How can I format Ruby `DateTime` to string, using  arithmetic operators?
Usual case:

```
time = Time.now.utc
#=> 2016-04-26 12:00:19 UTC
time.strftime("%Y %m")
#=> "2016 04"
```

I want, for instance, get output for months indexed starting at zero (January is month 0, December is month 11):

```
time.strftime("%Y %(m-1)") # or something similar method
#=> "2016 03" 
or 
#=> "2016 3"
```

Note: not change `time`

Comment: What do you mean by arithmetic operators? Do you mean like minus `-`? Or do you mean `strftime`?

Comment: i means like `-` inside `strftime`, or something similar method

Answer (score 1):

**Note** This is an answer to the original question, not an answer to the question after it has changed.

You cannot do it with `strftime`. Do it with interpolation or string format.

```
"%02d" % (time.month - 1)
# => "03"
```

Comment: You can easily incorporate the year: `"%d %02d" % [time.year, time.month - 1]`

Comment: @Stefan Yes, you are right. The OP has changed the question after I answered.

Answer (score 1):

`strftime` not allowed you to do such arithmetic as argument but You can separate `year` and `month`, perform your required action on month and concat as string.

```
> time.strftime("%Y ") + "#{time.strftime('%m').to_i - 1}"
#=> "2016 3"
> time.strftime("%Y ") + (time.strftime('%m').to_i - 1).to_s
#=> "2016 3"
```

**OR**

```
> time.year.to_s + " #{time.month - 1}"
#=> "2016 3"
```

Comment: Don't mix string concatenation and interpolation, choose one or the other.

Comment: @Stefan: I have mixed just because to show required output